# Trouble entering POST parameters into url for ".do" page

Tags: http, post, web-scraping, struts, uri

I'm doing some heavy web scraping using Python. In some cases, post data is sent not through a form submit but through some Javascript, which I cannot interact with via this approach. In order to circumvent this, I've been appending names and values for the post requests to the url and then visiting that url.

This method was working fine until I came across a site that used this kind of structure: **[sitename].com/?[pagename].do/.** I admit total ignorance about this .do extension, though some light searching tells me that it has to do with Struts and a Java-based backend. In this case it seems to be a way of dynamically generating a table; I'm trying to filter the results of that table. What I want to enter is something like **[sitename].com/?[pagename].do?[name]=[value]&[name]=[value]**, but this doesn't work, nor does it even seem like it should work. I attempted it using several variations in syntax. It seems like something I don't quite understand is going on here.

I wish I could direct you to the actual site, but unfortunately I cannot due to the sensitive nature of the project. Let me know, though, if there's any additional information that would be helpful in providing an answer. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is not really a "my code isn't working" question, as it's the underlying functionality that I would like to emulate in my code which is troubling me, but I'll do my best to get grittier. I'm contractually bound not to share the names of the sites that we're studying, but I will try to model the problem. I am hoping that someone with some familiarity of the back-end activity sending this .do page to the browser will be able to shed light.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
#
## case 1: a site that i have success in scraping
url = 'http://[sitename]/[pagename]' 
values = {'s' : '40', 'pg' : '1'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page #i get the filtered data that i am looking for

#
## case 2: the site that poses a problem for the encoding of post parameters
url = 'http://[sitename]/?[pagename].do/' # this site uses a .do file to generate 
        # the content i want to filter. note that the page name is preceded by ?. 
values = {'s' : '40', 'pg' : '1'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page # i am taken back to the root of the site, 
        # the same result i would get if i entered nonsense 
        # post parameters that did not correspond with actual control names.
```

here, also, is an example of some javascript on the page that accomplishes what i'd like to do with my scraper:

```
function page_next (id) {
$("#loading").fadeIn("normal");
   $.post("/?dumps.do/", {s: id, pg: 2},
      function( data ) {
                    var content = $( data ).find( '#dumps' );
           }
      )
}
```

Comment: I got downvoted, and I'm not sure why. Can someone tell me how I can make this question better, and/or how I can make it more likely to get some kind of feedback if not a total solution?

Maybe the problem is that my question is not directly found in some broken code. I can't even solve this problem by entering the proper syntax into the url bar in my browser, which is an action that I'd like to perform analogously in my scraping algorithm. In a sense this is a concrete and specific problem with a specific answer, even if that answer is "what you're attempting is not possible because X."

Comment: I was not the one to downvote, but people have a way at jumping to conclusions when they see "site scraping" and "sensitive nature of the project" in the same post. Just curious though, why do you need to parse the site?

Comment: ah, i see. that's fair. i am not doing evil deeds. i'm working with researchers who are building a database of certain folks who are. they have ushered me into heavy secrecy, i assume so that they don't spook the people they're collecting data on. it's hard enough as it is. of course, it's not possible for me to prove that and i could just as well be lying.

i don't know if the problem was solvable within the mechanize framework. i'm now working with selenium, not so much need to reverse engineer everything, and am doing okay. thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what site you are parsing, but this: `[sitename].com/?[pagename].do/` is not something I would call default Struts behaviour, assuming it's indeed a Struts application.

Having a `.do` extension was indeed something Struts used to use as request mapping, but the URL in that case should be `[sitename].com/[pagename].do` not `[sitename].com/?[pagename].do/`

In the second form, the action is in fact a parameter in a query string. This is why this syntax is broken: `[sitename].com/?[pagename].do?[name]=[value]&[name]=[value]`. You want to send a query string to the action but the action itself is a parameter in the query string.

But that's not the issue. The issue is that the site is doing something with that parameter and expects to receive it's data in a certain way, a way you were not able to reverse engineer.

Assuming again that this is a Struts application, Struts uses a front controller to intercept all `action.do` URLs and then use the action to invoke a particular class in the application, a class that is mapped to that particular action. The format for this should be `[sitename].com/[pagename].do`. That would be similar to having, say, `[sitename].com/[pagename].php`.

But having the action as a parameter makes me think that the site has a different front controller (not that of Struts) that is taking the parameter from the query string and passing it downstream to the Struts framework.

There could be a lot of reasons for having this funky way of handling requests, including making it harder for others to scrape the site, although this seems kinda straight forward:

```
$.post("/?dumps.do/", {s: id, pg: 2}, ...
```

Have you tried doing a POST to the root of the application with the action in the query string?